# How can i share my wired connection to my laptop wifi?

Tags: networking, network-shares, wireless-router

I have a wired internet broadband connection on my PC(win xp), i want to use this wired connection from my laptop(dell inspiron win 7, wifi). I also have a adsl2+ router. So can i configure this router and use this wired internet connection from my laptop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you just replace your wired router with a wireless router. If your existing router can be changed into a bridge, then you can use a wireless router without a built-in modem. That gives you more choices for the router but requires two devices. Otherwise, get an ADSL2+ wireless router.

Comment: I recently picked up a Wifi Link WirelessUSB Adapter, it was only a few dollars but it can act as a Wifi Link for any wired connections. It works great!

Comment: wired connection is directly connected to a NIC card, i have adsl2+ wireless router in spare, not in use. can i use that router and connect from my laptop to this wired connection on my pc?

Comment: @Mehakk: I would try to avoid having two routers if you possibly can. Instead, replace the wired router with the wireless router.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I don't have a router for my wired connection.

Comment: Your wireless router doesn't have wired ports?! What's the make/model?

Comment: Yes it has 4/ports, like LAN1.....LAN4.

Comment: Beetel 450TC1 ADSL2+ 4 Port Wireless Modem.

Comment: @Mehakk: Well there you go then. Connect your Internet connection to the router. Connect your PC to one of the wired ports.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Ok then how do i connect from my laptop?

Comment: What i need is i want to connect to this WiFi router from my laptop

Comment: @Mehakk: You cannot your laptop wirelessly.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to setting up an ad-hoc connection on your computer.

1. Go to Start > then right-click on Network and select Properties (on Windows Vista/7, go to your Network and Sharing Center under Start > Control Panel > Network and Internet).
2. Click on the "Set up a connection or network" option.
3. Select "Set up a wireless ad-hoc network" (Vista/7 have this as "Set up a new network"). Click Next.
4. Choose a name for your ad hoc network, enable encryption, and check the box to save the network. Your wireless network will then be created and your wireless adapter will start broadcasting.
5. Go to Network Connections in your Control Panel by going to Start > Control Panel > Network and Internet Connections > Network Connections.
6. Right-click your Internet connection that you want to share (e.g., Local Area Connection) and click Properties.
7. Click the Advanced tab.Under Internet Connection Sharing, check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"

Click OK and you will receive a message about your LAN adapter being set to 192.168.0.1.
Click Yes to confirm you want to enable Internet Connection Sharing.
Your Internet connection will now be shared to other computers on your local network; if you connect them via wire (either directly or through a wireless hub), you're all set.

CONVERSELY:

You can just set up your adsl2+ router and stick an ethernet cable running from one of the LAN ports to your computer and use that connection as wired while having a wireless connection NOT emanating from your laptop.

I would select the second method of using the router.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok its working good on my PC. I want to use this connection from my WiFi laptop. How do I do that?

Comment: sorry i'm afraid i don't understand. What works well on your PC? The initial portion of whats written above should allow you to start an adhoc network(which is what you want)